# Run X clients over multi-hop ssh tunnel

Tags: xorg, ssh-tunneling

I've recently converted my home development machine to Linux, and would like to be able to log into it from work if needed. I use a mixture of Linux and Windows machines, and I already have various gyrations of ssh/putty/Xorg/Cygwin/etc set up to launch X clients remotely and display on the local X server.

My problem is, my home machines are behind a firewall, and getting to them requires tunneling through the firewall over ssh. When I was running Windows I had set up ssh port forwarding on the firewall to bounce RDC connections to the correct machine, but it appears that X tunneling is more complex. Just enabling X11 forwarding on the ssh connection to the firewall only seems to work for X clients running on that machine, not ones I start on the second "hop".

Is there a way to forward/tunnel/whatever the X11 connection through the firewall and to a remote machine that's an extra hop away?

Side-Note:

I'm not particularly married to X11, so if there's some other option that will work better over multiple ssh hops, I'd take that as an answer (especially if you can tell me why it's better). I just happen to already have an Xorg-ish server on all of my work machines. The requirements are basically:

- Display-side-thingee (X server, RDC client, etc.) needs to run on Linux and Windows
- Application-side stuff just needs to run on Linux
- Needs to work over an ssh "tunnel" of at least 2 two hops.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets suppose that you have the following topology:

Work -> Firewall (port forwarding) -> Server -> Target.

If your problem is that you are not getting the X11 on `Target` because you are doing `ssh -X Server` and then inside `Server` you are doing `ssh -X Target` this might work for you.

`ssh` allows you to forward ports too. You can use a `ssh` connection to get a remote port mapped in a local port. For example to access `Target` one can:

Map the port `22` on `Target` to a local port `20000` using the `Server` connection (keep this connection open or use -Nf option).

`ssh -L20000:Target:22 Server`

Then connect to `Target` using this mapped port.

`ssh -p 20000 -X localhost`

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, this is setting up an ssh tunnel directly to the target machine so it only looks to X like one hop?  That sounds like it should work, I'll let you know...

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You are taking a remote port using a server as a bridge and mapping it to a local port. SSH allows you to do such things with -L (remote to local), -R (local ro remote) and -D (create a kind of proxy).

Comment: This is a useful technique, ando ften the best option, but be aware of the performance problems in running TCP over TCP when you have packet loss.

Comment: The connection between Target and Server here is secure or not?  As I understand, this might be a problem?

Comment: @SyrtisMajor as secure as an `ssh` connection since the data is being transported by `ssh` protocol.