# Run command over two ssh hops

Tags: ssh

Following [AWS best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html) I’ve set up an infrastructure to which I ssh via a bastion box:

```
localhost → bastion → target server
```

To connect to the target server I have keyfiles on localhost and the bastion box, and then I use ssh to hop as follows:

```
localhost > ssh -i key.pem bastion
bastion > ssh -i key.pem target
```

It looks like [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108085/run-x-clients-over-multi-hop-ssh-tunnel) is related. How do I execute a command on the target server from localhost directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ProxyCommand in your SSH config. So, in case you haven't set up your `~/.ssh/config`, I'd refer to [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)

So You would want to do the following:

1. Place the bastion as a Forward Agent in your SSH config.
2. Use ProxyCommand to proxy your connection from the bastion to your target server.

Here is a quick example:

```
Host <bastion>
    ForwardAgent yes

Host <target_server>
        User <user>
        Hostname <Ip/Hostname>
        ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p <user>@<bastion> nc 2> /dev/null
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command line I use the following to execute remote commands, for instance to run `top` on the target system.

```
$ ssh -qt bastion "ssh -qt target \"top\"\"
```

This will even work with `sudo` or `sudo su - user` to run as a specific user.

```
$ ssh -qt bastion "ssh -qt target \"sudo su - user1 -c 'ls -l'\""
```

Here's what the `ssh` options in the examples do.

- `ssh -q` = quiet, suppresses the banners from the server to miniminize distratctions.
- `ssh -t` = terminal, forces allocation of a pseudo-terminal so that terminal oriented commands like `top` and `sudo` will accept the session as interactive.